# Yii - Yii gets information out of scope

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I'm having a problem with a complex AR search in Yii, Could you help me please?

I'm doing an AR search like this:

`$property = Properties::model()->with(
                $this->propertiesConditions($photoid, $languageApp, $value->propertyid)
                )->findAll('t.id = :id', array('id'=>$value->propertyid));`

Where `$this->propertiesConditions` is a function which will return an array with the conditions which are necessary for the search (I don't know why it doesn't look with the correct spacing).

```
public function propertiesConditions($photoid, $languageApp, $propertyid)
{
    if (!is_null($photoid)) {
        return array(
                'owner', 
                'amenities',
                'i18npropertiesinfos'=>array('condition'=>'i18npropertiesinfos.iso6391code="'.$languageApp.'"'),
                'rates'=>array('condition'=>'rates.propertyid="'.$propertyid.'"', 'order'=>'price'),
                'images'=>array('condition'=>'images.id="'.$photoid.'"'),
                );
    }else{
        return array(
                'owner', 
                'amenities',
                'i18npropertiesinfos'=>array('condition'=>'i18npropertiesinfos.iso6391code="'.$languageApp.'"'),
                'rates'=>array('condition'=>'rates.propertyid="'.$propertyid.'"', 'order'=>'price'),
                );
    }
}
```

for some reason if the property doesn't have a $photoid ($photoid == null) it looks for the correct array (the one without the 'images') but when I send it to the view and var dump the property I get the object without the 'images' property (and that's great), but when I var_dump($property->images) I get an images model (and I don't know where it gets it)

Thanks.

EDIT (adding var_dumps as requested):

Property with an image:

```
object(Properties)[122]
  private '_new' (CActiveRecord) => boolean false
  private '_attributes' (CActiveRecord) => 
    array (size=13)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'slug' => string 'beach-house-123123-321321' (length=25)
      'title' => string 'Beach House' (length=11)
      'latitude' => string '123123' (length=6)
      'longitude' => string '321321' (length=6)
      'status' => string '0' (length=1)
      'ownerid' => string '1' (length=1)
      'videoURL' => string '' (length=0)
      'numberbedrooms' => null
      'numberbathrooms' => null
      'imagesOrder' => string '["1"]' (length=5)
      'sleeps' => string '2' (length=1)
      'featured' => string '1' (length=1)
  private '_related' (CActiveRecord) => 
    array (size=5)
      'owner' => 
        object(owners)[123]
          private '_new' (CActiveRecord) => boolean false
          private '_attributes' (CActiveRecord) => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
          private '_related' (CActiveRecord) => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private '_c' (CActiveRecord) => null
          private '_pk' (CActiveRecord) => string '1' (length=1)
          private '_alias' (CActiveRecord) => string 't' (length=1)
          private '_errors' (CModel) => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private '_validators' (CModel) => null
          private '_scenario' (CModel) => string 'update' (length=6)
          private '_e' (CComponent) => null
          private '_m' (CComponent) => null
      'amenities' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            object(amenities)[124]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(amenities)[128]
              ...
          2 => 
            object(amenities)[129]
              ...
      'i18npropertiesinfos' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(i18npropertiesinfo)[125]
              ...
      'rates' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            object(rates)[126]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(rates)[130]
              ...
      'images' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(images)[127]
              ...
  private '_c' (CActiveRecord) => null
  private '_pk' (CActiveRecord) => string '1' (length=1)
  private '_alias' (CActiveRecord) => string 't' (length=1)
  private '_errors' (CModel) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '_validators' (CModel) => null
  private '_scenario' (CModel) => string 'update' (length=6)
  private '_e' (CComponent) => null
  private '_m' (CComponent) => null
```

Property without an image:

```
object(Properties)[120]
  private '_new' (CActiveRecord) => boolean false
  private '_attributes' (CActiveRecord) => 
    array (size=13)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'slug' => string '' (length=0)
      'title' => string 'Maya House' (length=10)
      'latitude' => string '123123' (length=6)
      'longitude' => string '123123' (length=6)
      'status' => string '0' (length=1)
      'ownerid' => string '1' (length=1)
      'videoURL' => string '' (length=0)
      'numberbedrooms' => null
      'numberbathrooms' => null
      'imagesOrder' => string '[]' (length=2)
      'sleeps' => string '2' (length=1)
      'featured' => string '1' (length=1)
  private '_related' (CActiveRecord) => 
    array (size=4)
      'owner' => 
        object(owners)[121]
          private '_new' (CActiveRecord) => boolean false
          private '_attributes' (CActiveRecord) => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
          private '_related' (CActiveRecord) => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private '_c' (CActiveRecord) => null
          private '_pk' (CActiveRecord) => string '1' (length=1)
          private '_alias' (CActiveRecord) => string 't' (length=1)
          private '_errors' (CModel) => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private '_validators' (CModel) => null
          private '_scenario' (CModel) => string 'update' (length=6)
          private '_e' (CComponent) => null
          private '_m' (CComponent) => null
      'amenities' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            object(amenities)[131]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(amenities)[134]
              ...
          2 => 
            object(amenities)[135]
              ...
      'i18npropertiesinfos' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 =>
            object(i18npropertiesinfo)[132]
              ...
      'rates' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(rates)[133]
              ...
  private '_c' (CActiveRecord) => null
  private '_pk' (CActiveRecord) => string '2' (length=1)
  private '_alias' (CActiveRecord) => string 't' (length=1)
  private '_errors' (CModel) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '_validators' (CModel) => null
  private '_scenario' (CModel) => string 'update' (length=6)
  private '_e' (CComponent) => null
  private '_m' (CComponent) => null
```

Comment: Show the var_dump result of both cases

Comment: Added the requested var_dump

Comment: And if you set $property = null; and later the search

Comment: Where should I set the property null?

Comment: Before this part $property = Properties.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your find method, you select list of the `Properties` without `images` relation, it did not mean that all of properties record don't have any relationship with images. If some of them had relationship with the other image record, this line `$property->images` could still work.

I'm not sure what your point was, but if you intent to separate two cases only about list of properties whether has image or not, you could add more condition into the Properties model for the case there is not 'images'.
Example:

```
'notHasImages' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Images', array('id'=>'product_id'),
                        'condition'=>'images.product_id IS NULL'),
```

(Assumed that product_id is the foreign key of property on `Images` table) (ONE to MANY)

Comment: Hi!, thanks for your response, the properties table have the column "imagesOrder" which have a JSONStringified with all the images' id in the correct order. Now when a property doesn't have any image, (or it had but the image was removed) the string is "[]" and that's why I do all that stuff to check if it is empty or not but it doesn't matter if it is empty... I get the second property with an image that exists, but I don't know where it came from.

Comment: did my last comment help you to get a full image of my situation?

Comment: There were something that made you confused. Let me make an example: property id = 1 has 2 images, in order to meet your combination of conditions (in propertiesConditions), the array of images in the property record could be empty, but eventually, when you call the statement "property->images" for property id=1, it would show what property had. If image id = null, the result would not give you array of images even though that property could has because the second combination of the conditions did not contain 'images' relation

Comment: You were right, and the solution was to set null to the property which didn't have any image. Thanks!